# Hello World Boot Loader

Tags: loader, boot

I'm trying to do a hello world for a boot loader in assembly.
I'm following this tutorial:
http://www.osdever.net/tutorials/view/hello-world-boot-loader

I searched and it seems people are saying gcc doesn't work for compiling assembly. So I searched and found flat assembler. When I try to compile the example, it gives me an error at the first line [BITS 16]. Basically it states 'Illegal Instruction'.

What type of assembler does this code require?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if some tool in GCC can compile assembler (and if it does, whether it can compile to 16 bit code), but the site you refer to recommends NASM. Did you try it with NASM?

Comment: Yeah I didn't see that and now I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: I never used nasm. But man nasm tells me that it simply produces an object file based on an input (assembler) file. Syntax appears to be "nasm -o objectfile assemblerfile.asm. A file containing your first line there ([BITS 16]) doesn't produce an error so it should be what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried nasm with the "nothing boot loader" from your link. It works. "nasm nothing.asm" creates an object file "nothing". When I run "file nothing", my OS reports "nothing: x86 boot sector, code offset 0x0". I guess that is what you need. I could write it to a floppy disk now and boot from it. (Although it would do nothing, obviously.)

Answer (score 0):

I simply commented the line out and it worked in FASM. It seems like FASM defaults to 16 bit automatically. After it compiled, it generated a BIN file by the same name. I renamed it to an IMG extention and then assigned it as a Floppy Disk image using VirtualBox to test it. Worked great and booted.

As long as you write this BIN/IMG file to the drive on the first sector it seems to work okay. I used the tutorials on the above website also.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing square brackets around BITS 16 in case you didn't.

Comment: Please [edit] to rephrase into a more assertive answer. Maybe like "The problem might be ... . In that case the solution is ... ." That way of phrasing avoid the misonception (ny sloppy readers) that you are asking a question instead of answering. For bonus consider to provide a more detailed explanation of how and why this helps.